# Adding view to storyboard programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am loading a viewController via a storyboard segue and I want to add a `UIImageView` to the controller programmatically (instead of creating it in the storyboard). Usually when working without a Storyboard or NIB I would do this in `loadView:` is there an appropriate place for  this when using storyboards or does the storyboard drop you in a bit late in the day for that?

**EDIT:** Updated error regarding NIB and loadView:

Comment: In the case of storyboards I am now pretty sure that viewDidLoad is the best place to add what I need programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a NIB you shouldn't really be adding anything using `loadView:`. You should be using `viewDidLoad:`. This also works when using Storyboards.

Comment: You are right, that is my mistake, when I was using loadView I was not using a NIB I was creating the entire view hierarchy programatically. Thanks for pointing that out.